# How do I send my object's data from a list to the display page on android?

Tags: android

I am creating a pretty simple app that has a custom listItem (each listitem object contains a string, an integer, and a second integer value).

What I want to achieve is to allow the user to tap on the listitem, and have it open in a new screen.  it will simply display the same information.

However I feel a bit lost as a newbie.  How do I sent the listItem data from the first screen to the second?  I am trying to achieve something like this tutorial - but I cannot figure out how they made it work:  http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/twitter/intent-example-tweet-detail-screen-module

I've looked on stackoverflow for the answer, but I guess I don't know what to search for because I haven't found one

Comment: use an Intent to start the second activity. Put the data from the string into the Intent, and extract it in the second activity

Comment: Can I send the whole object at once?  I would prefer to understand how to send the entire object rather than sending one piece at a time

Comment: yes, you can send entire objects. Check Itent.putExtras() and Bundle. If your Object contains only Primitve types, then its better to put them in the Intent itself and create a new object in your second activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your class with Serializable.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial") //with this annotation we are going to hide compiler warning
public class CustomObject implements Serializable {

public CustomObject(double id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public double getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(double id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

private double id;
private String name;

}
```

We will send the object called customObject from X activity to Y activity. In your onItemClik

```
CustomObject customObject = new DCustomObjectneme(4,"YourName");
Intent i = new Intent(this, Y.class);
i.putExtra("sampleObject", customObject);
startActivity(i);
```

In Y activity we are getting the object.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
CustomObject customObject = (CustomObject)i.getSerializableExtra("sampleObject");
```

Try it.